# How to change letter case in URL with .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have problem with mod_rewrite in Apache [Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)] [Server built: Mar 19 2014 20:56:01]
I am working with project written in PHP CodeIgniter with such a .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /my_dir/
RewriteRule (.*)test/myAction(.*) $1Test/myAction$2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/mov .mov
```

As a result I want changing http://example.com/my_dir/test/myAction to http://example.com/my_dir/Test/myAction (uppercase letter T in my controller name)].
It works on Windows 8. Probably because Windows ignores letter case at all. But how to make it working on Linux? What is wrong with my .htaccess?
Additionally moving the line with first RewriteRule lower, results in "Internal server error".

My error.log shows something like this:

```
rewrite 'test/myAction' -> 'Test/myAction'
rewrite 'Test/myAction/myAction' -> 'index.php/Test/myAction/myAction'
forcing '/var/www/my_dir/index.php/Test/myAction/myAction' to get passed through to next API 
trying to replace prefix /var/www/my_dir/ with /my_dir/
internal redirect with /my_dir/index.php/Test/myAction/myAction [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
pass through /var/www/my_dir/index.php
rewrite 'Test/myAction/myAction' -> 'index.php/Test/myAction/myAction'
forcing '/var/www/index.php/Test/myAction/myAction' to get passed through to next API URI-to-filename handler
strip document_root prefix: /var/www/index.php/Test/myAction/myAction -> /index.php/Test/myAction/myAction
internal redirect with /index.php/Test/myAction/myAction [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Comment: What is `$0` meant to  become in `RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]`? That might be the cause for the "Internal error"...

Comment: To be honest it was default in CodeIgniter. Probably rewrites ?var=val to var/val. Not sure, but it was always there and was working.

Comment: Hm, never seen that. It might indeed be the capture of the whole request string. That would match the behavior of other regex matching engines. but you should check that, since you get an internal error at that place.

Comment: Thanks. I will check that. But do you think my line is correct? Is it in the right place? This is the main problem.

Comment: The other thing, about the upper case `T`... The rewriting log clearly shows that the rewriting _does_ change the letters case. So what is the problem?

Comment: Problem is when hiting http://example.com/my_dir/test/myAction my framework reacts in another way than when hiting http://example.com/my_dir/Test/myAction. Second URL displays correctly but first one returns error (module not found). It should be the same module!

Comment: Might be, but as said: the rewriting log proves that the rewriting works as expected. So the problem must be somewhere else... I'd say you have to trace in to how that request get's processed. Maybe again some issue with letter cases in the naming of files to be loaded in background? Any entries in the error log file?

Comment: When moving my line lower (Internal server error) error log says "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error." - redirect loop.

Comment: And when my line in .htaccess is as in the example listed above, the log I pasted is in error.log, not in access.log.

Comment: Sorry, above you claimed this is you rewrite log. That should be separate from your error or access log. Ah, now you changed it... strange...

Comment: Yes, made a correction. Since Apache 2.4 or something like that the log way changed. You cannot use RewriteLog command in config any longer.

Comment: That is true. But back to your question: I still do not see why you claim that changing that letters case does not work. It _does_ work. That your application fails to show the same behavior must have some other reasons as said above. And the rewriting loop, well that also has nothing to do with changing the letters case, does it? It is a rewrite loop. I'd say that rewrite rule with the `L` flag matches again and again...

Comment: Hmm must check this again but the assumption was, that I will get the same result with lower and upper letter. That was my expectation.
Wanted to force .htaccess to changein the fly the lower letter to Upper and application should act the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I think the doubling of your "myAction" URL component might be a bug/issue related to the [DPI] flag.  Have you tried it on the rewriterules?

By default, PATH_INFO is spilled and restored. But if you capture and append it, as you do, you end up with a repeat.